# Hibernate ManyToOne Validation Schema Validation Error Starting WildFly

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, ejb-3.1, wildfly-10

I have an issue and i've spent a lot of time trying to figure it out and i cannot really come up with any other possible solution and i really need your help to see if i'm missing something here....

The table SYS_USER and SYS_ROLE have a OneToMany relationship and ManyToOne respectively and the look as the following (i'm pasting only relevant information)

**SysRole.java**

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="user_name", nullable=false)
public SysUser getSysUser() {
    return this.sysUser;
}

public void setSysUser(SysUser sysUser) {
    this.sysUser = sysUser;
}
```

**SysUser.java**

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="sysUser")
public Set<SysRole> getSysRoles() {
    return this.sysRoles;
}

public void setSysRoles(Set<SysRole> sysRoles) {
    this.sysRoles = sysRoles;
}
```

The database looks like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE `SYS_ROLE` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`role_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`role_type` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `FK_USERS` (`user_name`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_USERS` FOREIGN KEY (`user_name`) REFERENCES `SYS_USER`
(`user_name`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION) 
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `SYS_USER` (
`user_id` int(10) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`user_password` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
`user_first_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`user_last_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`user_email` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
UNIQUE KEY `user_name_UNIQUE` (`user_name`),
UNIQUE KEY `user_id_UNIQUE` (`user_id`)) 
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

the error i get on server startup is:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException:
Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in 
column [user_name]
in table [SYS_ROLE]; 
found [varchar (Types#VARCHAR)], 
but expecting [integer (Types#INTEGER)]
```

I could verify that moving the primary key from the field ID to the **'SYS_USER.user_id'** field, solves the problem, but ideally i would prefer that the **'SYS_USER.user_name'** would not be a PK as it has to be changed from time to time (still, should be unique).

All entities have been Auto Generated with Hibernate Reveng, no particular settings or remapping in the file.

Thanks a lot!
Dave

Comment: @JoinColumn(name="user_name", nullable=false) should be replaced with     @JoinColumn(name="user_id", nullable=false)

Comment: Thank you Abdullah. Unfortunately that wasnt what i wanted to avoid because i still want to be able to join on **user_name** to use the relationship getters, but didn't want the getter on the ID.

I did find a workaround which is:

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_name", nullable=false, **referencedColumnName = "user_name"**)
    public SysUser getSysUser() {
        return this.sysUser;
    }

Like this i still use the ID column as a PK but have a FK enforced on the user_name. I still have to figure out how to configure hibernate Reveng for auto-generation...